# asp.net get Last Id threats

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers

I have to tables , first one is [TempTable1] and second is [Table1] 
.First I insert data into [TempTable1] , after updating [confirmed] column in it , a Trigger [trigger1] moves a specific record depend on ID to [Table1] , what I want here is to get currently added record ID of the [Table1] in c# code , I thought about getting last record, but what I afraid of is conflating , because when a user confirms its data , they will transformed from [TempTable1] to [Table1] , and maybe user2 do the same , user3 also and so on.. if I always get last added id , may some users net is slow and it takes time for server to do the transformation , someones net is quick , its data maybe added before first user get its respond by getting its id, so may some ones id goes to another one when I get it in c# code and do operation on it , am I true or there is no threat in doing this ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you need to process all of the "new" rows that have not been handled already, then add another column, e.g. `ConfirmationCompleted`, and use either a `bit` or nullable `datetime` to keep track of the rows that need to be processed.

Comment: Yes I've used bit,nut what I want to accomplish is , when a user submits his Ad , he must review his ad again an then confirm it, after confirmation the ad is transformed to another table , in the new table I need the ID of this users ad in the second table , but the transformation is done by a trigger not EF object, how can I get this new ID of this ad in the second table

Comment: Are you saying that the trigger doesn't have access to the identification or that you don't have access to the trigger?  Or something ekse entirely?

Comment: No , I'm saying that , my trigger in sql server transform a record from table1 to table2, I want to know the ID of new added record in table to usnin Entity Framework

Comment: Okay, so you just want the trigger to output the identification(s) for access by EF. The trigger could mark new entries in `table2`, e.g. with a `bit`, and you can use EF to query for those rows and clear the flag. Or the trigger could write the identifications to a separate table and you could delete them after they are processed. In either case you need to have an application using EF to poll occasionally and check for new data.

Comment: I need only one flag at a time,when a User submits his data and then confirmed it, by clicking on Confirm button,the confirmed column of that data record is updated, the Trigger1 works and transform this record to table2,and rises the flag, at the next statement in c# code using EF I'll use the flagged record in table2 and down the flag,but what if between updating,transforming statement and getting back the ID there was a delay,and another user did same it will be two flags rise at a time,how do I know which one is for which user,Or is such a delay between two statements predictable?

Comment: A properly written trigger can process more than one row, so you ought to have a design that allows you to handle more than one new row in `table2`. Either an extra column in `table2` or a separate table will work. In any event, by the time the application using EF looks for something new there could have been more than one user confirmation processed. Note: If your trigger _cannot_ process more than one row then please test for multiple rows and use `RaIsError` to announce to the world that it is incapable of handling multiple rows.